# iOS-values being printed NULL outside for loop,but prints well inside the for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, ios6

I am posting the code which i have tried.

```
 .h file
    --------------
    @property (nonatomic,retain)  NSString *selectedChannelIDAlert;
    @property (nonatomic,retain)  NSString *pNewString;

    .m file
    -----------
    @synthesize selectedChannelIDAlert,pNewString;

    -(void)callfun{
    NSArray *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        selectedChannelIDAlert=[jsonData valueForKeyPath:@"items.snippet.resourceId.channelId"];

        for (pNewString in selectedChannelIDAlert) {

            NSLog(@"inside:%@",pNewString);

        }
    NSLog(@"outside:%@",pNewString);
    }

My output is
--------
2013-12-24 17:38:01.590 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCK376qNDlNZZDNHsnaWuTeg
2013-12-24 17:38:01.892 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UC6Ju00QIPQw2mCcUSrbyQKQ
2013-12-24 17:38:02.200 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCshoKvlZGZ20rVgazZp5vnQ
2013-12-24 17:38:02.750 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCVzbLPpZ_VMqDzUtmN3uU9A
2013-12-24 17:38:03.429 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCo0vVHI3Oz7O5zTc6f-5lgw
2013-12-24 17:38:03.735 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCqg2eLFNUu3QN3dttNeOWkw
2013-12-24 17:38:04.144 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCrYnLkVfvVf0Qy0YOUQdk2A
2013-12-24 17:38:04.574 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCCOIC6NrBFrVCcI7tcXNWpQ
2013-12-24 17:38:04.966 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCcMTZY1rFXO3Rj44D5VMyiw
2013-12-24 17:38:05.374 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UC-wwO4iPfQtoNjbS792Mpzg
2013-12-24 17:38:05.685 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCrSi7xopc9-SWRMydSq5e1Q
2013-12-24 17:38:06.090 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw
2013-12-24 17:38:06.500 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCEe076nFuVobN0bAsXK7ICw
2013-12-24 17:38:06.913 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UCgSHGbs2oGoLItc-8y5hJ9g
2013-12-24 17:38:07.318 TubeAlert[1230:907] inside:UC-LPIU24bQXVljUXivKEeRQ
2013-12-24 17:38:07.730 TubeAlert[1230:907] outside:(null)
```

So please tell me where I am going wrong ,so that I can get result printed both inside and outside the for loop.Thanks

Comment: becz "pNewString" its scope is  valid within the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to use a property as a loop variable in a `for`-`in` loop.

In your example, the value of the variable `pNewString` is controlled by the `for`-`in` loop, meaning that it is valid only inside the body of that loop. Once the loop has finished, accessing the value is not safe: fast enumeration that is used behind the scene to implement the `for`-`in` loop can set it to an arbitrary value, which appears to be `nil` for Cocoa's `NSArray`s.

To avoid this issue in the future, consider declaring your `pNewString` variable in the loop's scope, like this:

```
for (NSString * NSString in jsonData) {
    ...
}
```

If you would like to get the last value from the array, use

```
NSLog(@"outside:%@", [jsonData lastObject]);
```

Comment: and if i want my whole data outside the loop too,then how can i modify my code

Comment: @wimcNilesh If you want the whole data outside the loop, store the entire `jsonData` collection in a property. Then it will be available for future reference when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

you're try to print the `pNewString` when it's out of scope. it becomes `nil` after the for loop completes.